# Measure Theoretic rigorous formulation/definition of the Expectation Maximization algorithm (EM Algorithm)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, maximum-likelihood

$\newcommand{\cY}{\mathcal{Y}}\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}\newcommand{\cX}{\mathcal{X}}\newcommand{\Rbb}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\Pbb}{\mathbb{P}}\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}\newcommand{\vY}{\vect{Y}}\newcommand{\vy}{\vect{y}}\newcommand{\vX}{\vect{X}}\newcommand{\vx}{\vect{x}}\newcommand{\vtheta}{\vect{\theta}}\newcommand{\vz}{\vect{z}}\newcommand{\vZ}{\vect{Z}}$

## Aim: Rigorous Formulation of EM Algorithm

I am trying to write a rigorous treatment of the Expectation-Maximization algorithm (EM algorithm), however, I couldn't find it anywhere. I also tried reading the paper by Dempster that introduced it but it doesn't really use any measure theory.

## My Current Formulation for Missing Data Setting

### Observed or Incomplete data

Let $(\cY, \cF_{\cY}, \Pbb_{\cY})$ be a probability space and let $(\Rbb,\cB(\Rbb))$ be a measurable space.
Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ be $n$ random variables defined as follows:
$$
Y_i:\cY\to\Rbb
$$
We define a *random vector* $\vY:=(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)^\top$ and we call **incomplete** or **observed** data any vector
$$
\vy:=(y_1, \ldots, y_n)^\top
$$
containing realizations of the $n$ random variables $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$.

### Missing Data

Similarly, we call **missing** data any vector
$$
\vx:=(x_1, \ldots, x_m)^\top
$$
of realizations of the $m$ random variables $\vX:=(X_1, \ldots, X_m)^\top$ defined on the same probability space $(\cX, \cF_{\cX}, \Pbb_{\cX})$ and taking values in $\Rbb$.

## Problem: How to define a density function on concatenation of random variables from different probability spaces?

Now, what most people do next is to concatenate the observed and the missing data into a vector $\vz:=(\vx^\top, \vy^\top)^\top$ which is assumed to be the realization of a **complete data** random vector $\vZ$ and then define
$$
p_{\vY}(\vY=\vy; \vtheta) := \int_{\cB(\Rbb)} p_{\vX}(\vy, \vx; \vtheta) d\vx
$$
How does this make any sense? Surely since $\vY$ and $\vX$ are defined on different probability spaces, we cannot simply concatenate the realizations $\vy$ and $\vx$ to obtain the realization of some new random vector $\vZ$. What is $\vZ$ actually made of? I would assume
$$
\vZ:=(X_1, \ldots, X_m, Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)^\top
$$
but then $m$ of the elements of $\vZ$ are defined on $(\cX, \cF_{\cX}, \Pbb_{\cX})$ and the remaining $n$ elements are defined on $(\cY, \cF_{\cY}, \Pbb_{\cY})$. But in the wikipedia page of a random vector we see that all the components of $\vZ$ should be defined on the same probability space. (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable))

How do we actually formulate the EM algorithm in a formal way?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\cY}{\mathcal{Y}}\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}\newcommand{\cX}{\mathcal{X}}\newcommand{\Rbb}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\Pbb}{\mathbb{P}}\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}\newcommand{\vY}{\vect{Y}}\newcommand{\vy}{\vect{y}}\newcommand{\vX}{\vect{X}}\newcommand{\vx}{\vect{x}}\newcommand{\vtheta}{\vect{\theta}}\newcommand{\vz}{\vect{z}}\newcommand{\vZ}{\vect{Z}}$
One possible way to write a complete and rigorous (possibly, measure-theoretic) formulation of the EM algorithm might be the following.

## EM Algorithm Formulation

### Complete Data

Let $(\Omega, \cF, \Pbb)$ be a probability space and let $(\Rbb, \cB(\Rbb))$ be a measurable space. Suppose we have $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n$ random variables defined as
$$
Z_i: \Omega \to \Rbb \qquad \forall\,\,i\in\{1, \ldots, n\}
$$
We construct a **random vector** $\vZ:=(Z_1, \ldots, Z_n)^\top$ and we call any vector $\vz:=(z_1, \ldots, z_n)^\top$ of realizations of the random variables $Z_i$, the **complete data**.

### Incomplete or Observed Data

Now let $m<n$ be the number of *observed* data points. We simply rename the first $m$ random variables in $\vZ$ as follows
$$
Y_i := Z_i \qquad \text{for } i=1, \ldots, m
$$
and construct the random vector
$$
\vY:=(Y_1, \ldots, Y_m)^\top:=(Z_1, \ldots, Z_m)^\top
$$
then we denote the realizations of such random variables as 
$$
\vy:=(y_1, \ldots, y_m)^\top:=(z_1, \ldots, z_m)^\top
$$
and we call them **observed data**.

### Missing Data

Similarly, suppose that we have $p:=n-m$ missing data points. Then we rename the remaining $n-m$ random variables in $\vZ$ as follows
$$
X_{i-m}:= Z_i \qquad \text{for } i=m+1, \ldots, n
$$
and we construct the random vector 
$$
\vX :=(X_1, \ldots, X_p)^\top := (Z_{m+1}, \ldots, Z_n)^\top
$$ 
then we rename the realizations of such random variables
$$
\vx := (x_1, \ldots, x_p)^\top := (z_{m+1}, \ldots, z_n)^\top
$$
and we call them **missing data**.

### Definition of complete-data cumulative distribution function

Following wikipedia's definition of a [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition) as a [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Definition) the distribution for $Z_i$, denoted $\mu_{Z_i}$. Basically the distribution of $Z_i$ is the **pushforward probability measure** 
$$
\mu_{Z_i}: \cB(\Rbb)\to [0, 1]
$$
that satisfies
$$
\mu_{Z_i}(B)= \Pbb(Z_i^{-1}(B)) = \Pbb(Z_i\in B) = \Pbb(\left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, Z_i(\omega) \in B\right\}) \qquad \forall \, B\in \cB(\Rbb)
$$
That is, to any set $B$ of complete data points it gives the same measure / magnitude as the probability measure $\Pbb$ gives to the pre-image of $B$ under $Z_i$. In other words, it measures the probability that a data point $z_i$ takes a value in $B$. Next, we can define the **cumulative distribution function** as the function
$$
F_{\mu_{Z_i}}: \Rbb\to [0,1]
$$
that behaves as follows
$$
F_{\mu_{Z_i}}(z_i) := \mu_{Z_i}\left((-\infty, z_i]\right) =\Pbb\left(Z_i\in(-\infty, z_i]\right)=\Pbb\left(Z_i\leq z_i\right) \qquad \text{for } (-\infty, z_i]\in\cB(\Rbb)
$$
Then we can find the **joint probability distribution** of the random vector $\vZ$ as the pushforward probability measure 
$$
\mu_{\vZ}:\cB(\Rbb^n)\to [0, 1]
$$
satisfying the following for every $B:=B_1\times\ldots\times B_n\in\cB(\Rbb^n)$
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_{\vZ}(B) :&= \Pbb\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, Z_1(\omega)\in B_1\right\}\cup\ldots\cup\left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, Z_n(\omega)\in B_n\right\}\right) \\
&= \Pbb\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, Z_i(\omega)\in B_i\right\}\right)
\end{align}
$$
We can therefore define a **joint cumulative distribution**
$$
F_{\mu_{\vZ}}(\vz) : \Rbb^n \to [0, 1]
$$
as follows
$$
\begin{align}
F_{\mu_{\vZ}}(\vz) :&= \mu_{\vZ}\left(\left((-\infty, z_1], \ldots, (-\infty, z_n]\right)\right) \\
&= \Pbb\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,Z_i(\omega)\in(-\infty, z_i]\right\}\right) \\
&=  \Pbb\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, Z_i(\omega)\leq z_i\right\}\right) \\
&= \Pbb\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, Z_1(\omega)\leq z_1 \vee Z_2(\omega)\leq z_2 \vee \ldots \vee Z_n(\omega)\leq z_n\right\}\right) \\
&= \Pbb(Z_1\leq z_1, \ldots, Z_n\leq z_n)
\end{align}
$$

## Definition of Complete-Data Density / Likelihood function

Given another measure
$$
\mu: \cB(\Rbb) \to [0,1]
$$
The probability density of the random variable $Z_i$ is any *measurable function* $f$
$$
f: \Rbb\to [0, \infty)
$$
such that
$$
\mu_{Z_i}(B) = \int_B f d\mu \qquad \forall \, B\in\cB(\Rbb)
$$
That is, any measurable function whose integral with respect to $\mu$ over a set $B\in\cB(\Rbb)$ of possible data point realizations is given exactly by the value of the distribution $\mu_{Z_i}$ on $B$.

Similarly, for $B:=B_1\times\ldots\times B_n\in \cB(\Rbb^n)$ we say that $f$ 
$$
f: \Rbb^n \to [0, \infty)
$$
is the joint density of $\vZ$ if it is measurable and
$$
\mu_{\vZ}(B) = \int_{B} f d\mu
$$
Now suppose that the function $f$ can be parametrized by a vector of parameters $\vtheta\in\Theta\subseteq \Rbb^d$. We write
$$
f: \Rbb^n\to[0, \infty)\qquad f(\vz; \vtheta) := p(\vZ=\vz; \vtheta)
$$

## Writing the EM Algorithm in Full